# Using a vector as the default arglist of a function

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'd like to use a vector as the default selection for an function. In my real function, I have many more unique values and I'd like to dynamically pass them as the default selection. The example below works just fine, but I would like for the values within `class_list$class` to be shown in the yellow comment box and the `roxygen` documentation.

Is this possible?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)

class_list <- 
  mpg %>% 
  distinct(class)

avg_hwy <- function(set_class = class_list$class){
  mpg %>% 
    filter(class %in% set_class) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(cty))
}



avg_hwy()
avg_hwy("compact")
avg_hwy("suv")
```

Comment: A function like that is fine for interactive use, but in a package (and hence, whenever you're using `roxygen`) having a function default be some (possibly undefined) object hopefully floating around is bad practice. So I doubt you'll find a way to make this work.

Comment: I agree with @Gregor but I think you might be able to achieve this with the `@usage` parameter?  I can't test at the moment though.

Comment: It looks similar to enumerations (eg. https://github.com/aryoda/R_enumerations). You get intellisense, but only limited roxygen support (function signature). Disclaimer: It is "my" package